# Separating matching nodes in a query result

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I defined the directed relation `Know` on person nodes. For example, if Sara knows Alice then Sara-> Alice. I wrote this Cypher query to find all the people who know both the right and left side of the directed relation.

```
match ((n:Person)-[:Know]-> (m:Person)),(p:Person)
where EXISTS ((m)<-[:Know]-(p)-[:Know]->(n))
RETURN m,n,p
```

I need to get subgraphs with 3 nodes in the query's result but the result I get is a graph with many nodes. Is there any method to change the query to generate subgraphs with just 3 nodes (for example, a subgraph of Alex-> Sara, Alex-> Alice, Sara-> Alice and if Sara has the same condition on two other people it is shown in another subgraph). This requires repeating some nodes in the output.

Comment: You want 3-person cliques, essentially?

Comment: That's what I need to represent kind of analysis but it is not mandatory. The thing that I want is more clear representation of cliques.

Answer (score 0):

`MATCH` clauses are more flexible than that. Try this:

```
MATCH (n:Person)-[:Know]->(m:Person)<-[:Know]-(p:Person)-[:Know]->(n)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (()-[:Know]->(p))
    AND NOT EXISTS {
        WITH m, n, p
        MATCH (q:Person)-[:Know]->(m)
        WHERE q <> n 
            AND q <> p
    }
    AND NOT EXISTS {
        WITH m, n, p
        MATCH (q:Person)-[:Know]->(n)
        WHERE q <> p
    }
RETURN m, n, p
```

You might have to use a unique ID property, and I'm not sure if the `WITH` clause will work here as I've gotten it; but with subqueries, you are generally able to import variables from above using `WITH`.

Comment: This query generates the same big graph that I had but is an optimum query. Still there is no subgraphs in it.

Comment: I've added some conditions that might work to force cliques. Can you please try them out?